# Explanation needed in CLISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Can anyone explain the part with the flet operator please ? :

```
(defun read-3-numbers-&-format-sum ()
  (flet ((prompt (string)
           (format t "~&~a: " string)
           (read nil 'eof nil)))
    (let ((x (prompt "first number"))
          (y (prompt "second number"))
          (z (prompt "third number")))
      (format t "~&the sum of ~a, ~a, & ~a is:~%~%~a~%"
              x y z (+ x y z)))))
```

Comment: The `prompt` function also lacks a call to `finish-output`, to make sure that all printed content is actually displayed. This is important because output could be buffered and in some implementations then the prompt string will not be displayed when waiting for input.

Answer (score 3):

Your source for Common Lisp documentation is the Common Lisp Hyperspec, which can be found at different places on the internet.

Look up `flet` there: http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_flet_.htm#flet

It establishes a local function definition. Its scope is its body (i. e. where the `let` form is in this case). The function definition works like a “normal” function defined with defun otherwise.

Comment: Be slightly careful: `flet` is different than `defun` in that free references to the function name do not refer to the function being defined.